# Python change index for value array

Tags: python, arrays

In python I have the following array:

```
['75920-c1-u1 .pdf', '75920-c1-u2 .pdf', '75920-c1-u3 .pdf', '75920-c1-u4 .pdf', '75920-c1-u5 .pdf' , '75920-c1.pdf']
```

I would like to make the element: 75920-c1.pdf be on the index 0 and after it the rest should follow, so 75920-c1-u1 .pdf, 75920-c1-u2 .pdf etc...

I can't even manage to do this...

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: `[array[-1]] + array[:-1]`

Comment: Are you trying to sort in some way or simply change the order of a single list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
    ls = ['75920-c1-u1 .pdf', '75920-c1-u2 .pdf', '75920-c1-u3 .pdf', '75920-c1-u4 .pdf', '75920-c1-u5 .pdf' , '75920-c1.pdf']
    ls.sort(key=lambda s:(len(s),s))
    # ls = ['75920-c1.pdf', '75920-c1-u1 .pdf', '75920-c1-u2 .pdf', '75920-c1-u3 .pdf', '75920-c1-u4 .pdf', '75920-c1-u5 .pdf']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to (simple, but not necessarily the solution for large lists) slice your list or write a sort function.

Slicing could be done by (I assume you called it "array" bc it is a np array?) list(NP_ARRAY)[-1]+list(NP_ARRAY)[:-1].

A list named "name" is sliced from a to b by name[a:b]. The - means count from the end.

A sort function should split the string after '75920-c1' and sort from there.

Answer (score 0):

just pop the value and insert it in the first index
here is the code

```
a= ['75920-c1-u1 .pdf', '75920-c1-u2 .pdf', '75920-c1-u3 .pdf', '75920-c1-u4 .pdf', '75920-c1-u5 .pdf' , '75920-c1.pdf']
p = a.pop()
a.insert(0,p)
```

Hope it helps :)